# How to retrieve auth keys for an ACI deployment in Azure Portal (or Cloud Shell)?

Tags: azureportal, azure-aks, azure-container-instances, azure-cloud-shell, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a [deployment on ACI with Azure ML service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where#aci), and its status is healthy.
When deploying, I set `auth_enabled=True`, so that the service requires authorization keys to respond.

I can get the service auth keys for that deployment in my Azure ML service workspace `ws` in a Python console via

```
from azureml.core.webservice import Webservice
services = Webservice.list(ws)
services[0].get_keys()
```

However, it would be convenient to access to this information through Azure Portal or the Cloud Shell.

In Azure Portal (differently to what happens for AKS) there's no auth fields shown, also when accessing Advanced Settings by trying to edit the deployment:

[image]

Can you suggest ways to access those credentials?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [Azure Machine Learning CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/reference-azure-machine-learning-cli) to the cloudshell by running

```
az extension add -n azure-cli-ml
```

after that, you can retrieve the keys for any service by running

```
az ml service get-keys --name magical-service --workspace-name davide-workspace
```